# p:fileUpload not working inside p:dialog in primefaces 3.5

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new in prime-faces & using `p:fileUpload` inside `p:dialog` ,but when I click the button on which `p:dialog` is set to show dialog box is not coming, giving some error on browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function fileupload.js?ln=primefaces:11
PrimeFaces.widget.FileUpload.PrimeFaces.widget.BaseWidget.extend.init fileupload.js?ln=primefaces:11
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you use jquery independently in your project

Comment: yes i am using in my project